# How to get rid border below Table View cell in UIStoryboard?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

There is no problem with the default colors of Table View and its cells:

[image: White Table View]

But after I changed background color to black I found a line below each cell  (highlighted by red) which does not comply with indented lines below empty cells of table view:

[image: Black Table View]

Comment: welcome to Stack overflow please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: These lines are cell separators. You can set it to "none" in storyboard by selecting tableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the table view option and change separator to none

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try This: Go To TableView And select separator to none and set separator inset to  0 0 to left and right

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add separator color of tableView cell programmatically by using this

**Obj C**

```
 [self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor myColor]]; // provide your color
```

**Swift**

```
tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.redColor() // provide your color
```